# CSS missing from django admin pages on development server after execution of drop database

Tags: django, django-admin

I have been messing around with a simple django 1.3 toy project using MySQL, and decided to change a lot of my models around. After doing so, I needed to clear the database and "start afresh" so I used "drop database db" in the mysql prompt. However, after re-running

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

which correctly populated the database with the new tables, prompted me to make a superuser, etc... my admin pages no longer find the css files they are linked to (base.css for instance)

I did not change any settings, and am still using the built-in server with

`python manage.py runserver`

From googling around, it seems like there is some problem with my permissions, but every other discussion I have been able to find has said that this is only a problem when using apache or the like rather than the "automagical" django server.

As additional information, I am running Ubuntu 11.04 on a VirtualBox virtual machine under Windows 7. I also attempted to try and switch to sqlite3 in case I had somehow broken my mysql database, but that did not resolve the issue.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: is ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'  written in your settings.py file ?

Comment: @Boris Same exact problem with the development server.  Did you ever fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to include the the [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#with-a-context-processor) in your settings.py

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py uncomment(if commented) or add 'django.contrib.staticfiles', and restart the server. This should fix it.